# how to get the "index-as" value from html to javascript through on-tap function?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I tried this but it is not working, the parentIndex value is not defined in javascript

```js
_addAttribute: function(e) {
  console.log(e.model.parentIndex);
}
```

```html
I wrote html like this

<paper-button on-tap="_addAttribute(this.parentIndex)">Add</paper-button>
<template id="[[count]]" is="dom-repeat" items="{{parameters}}" index-as="parentIndex" restamp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `this.parentIndex`in `paper-button` element like:

```
<paper-button on-tap="_addAttribute">Add</paper-button>
```

you will still `e` property inside the function. 
Polymer does not support sending a property to function like JS. Just console log `e.model`